# How can I get the effect of a Band-Aid -like tape?

Tags: adhesive

Is there a way to make or get Band-Aid tape? I want a skin-applicable adhesive that works without the absorbent patch on it. Is there another similar tape or a way to get this kind of sticky adhesive without cutting up a dozen band-aids?

Comment: Do you mean something other than standard [first aid tape](https://www.google.com/search?q=first+aid+tape&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=opUmVfCrFcW2sAWU9YHgDA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAw&biw=1455&bih=705)?

Comment: @Geobits Yeah, that is nowhere near as adhesive as band-aid tape and doesn't hold to the skin as long. Band-aid tape is perfect, i just need more than tiny bits.

Comment: You may want to ask on our up-and-coming [health site](http://health.stackexchange.com/) since there is a fair deal of first-aid-related questions and they would most likely know what "tape" would be most analogous to the Band-Aid-like material.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of porous medical and surgical tapes on the market.  Band-Aids are made of different materials like latex or fabric, so I'm not sure which kind you are looking for.  Most of the major brands sell something.  A good medical supply store or drug store will have some choices.

Here are a couple of manufacturers.  You can explore their offerings to get a better idea of what you want.

[3M](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/3MC3SD/Wound-Care/Products/Wound-Care-Supplies/~/Critical-Chronic-Care/Medical-Tape?N=6232&rt=c3), [Johnson & Johnson](http://www.band-aidbrandfirstaid.com/first-aid-wound-products/tapes-wraps-bandages)

Answer (score 1):

Leucoplast - comes in rolls in two different widths. Sticks well, no padding anywhere, just a roll of tape, and can be cut to whatever size and shape you want. Alternatively, ordinary zinc oxide plaster tape comes similarly on a roll, no padding, but often doesn't stick so well, particularly if you're cutting very small pieces to use.

Answer (score 0):

I personally hate bandaid material, but here are possibly some alternatives:

- [Scotch Tape.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_Tape) This is a mild tape, that has good adhesive qualities when not in greasy, wet or similar environments. This should not make your skin irritated.
- Painters or [similar tape](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masking_tape) also works. This tape has better adhesive  than scotch and bandaid materials. Also, faces better in greasy, and wet environment.

**Other methods**

- [Surgical tape.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgical_tape)
- [Coban](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adhering_bandage).